# Element wise merging of lists python

Tags: python

To merge the elements of two lists like the following, it is very easy:

```
one = [['hi', 'hello'], ['namaste']]
two = [['hi', 'bye'], ['namaste']]

[m+n for m,n in zip(one,two)]
```

However, if I had a list greater than length 2, how can this be done? For example, concatenating each element in the list of list of lists that follows:

```
three = [['hi', 'why'], ['bye']]
list_ = [one, two, three]
```

I want an output like: `[['hi', 'hello', 'hi', 'bye', 'hi', 'why'], ['namaste', 'namaste', 'bye']]`

How can this be done in a scalable way, which works with even a `list_` of length 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use *extended iterable unpacking* operator in combination with `zip` method.

```
from itertools import chain
one = [['hi', 'hello'], ['namaste']]
two = [['hi', 'bye'], ['namaste']]
three = [['hi', 'why'], ['bye']]
list_ = [one, two, three]
result = [list(chain.from_iterable(elem)) for elem in zip(*list_)]
```

Output

```
[['hi', 'hello', 'hi', 'bye', 'hi', 'why'], ['namaste', 'namaste', 'bye']]
```

Comment: Answered it just a min before :)

Comment: its Cool to see same exact thinking

Answer (score 3):

the following code will scale

```
from itertools import chain
out = []
for each in zip(*list_):
    out.append(list(chain.from_iterable(each)))
```

Or a single liner

```
print([list(chain.from_iterable(each)) for each in zip(*list_)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that they're all the same size:

```
a = []

for i in len(one):
    a.append([])
    for list in list_:
        a[-1] += list[1]
```

even better, in a list comprehension:

```
import itertools    

[list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([list[x] for list in list_])) for x in len(one)]
```